# Parsing Twitter JSON

Tags: iphone, xcode

I've written some code to fetch data from a Twitter search and shove it in a `UITableView`, but I get a syntax error stating `No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'objectForKey:`

Here is the code that I am using to grab the `JSON` data:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    NSDictionary *allDataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];

    NSArray *feed = [allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"results"];

    NSString *text = [feed objectForKey:@"text"];

    [array addObject:text];

    [[self myTableView] reloadData];    
}
```

[Here is the JSON data itself](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=hatlive) (Press "Viewer" in the top left)

Any help? Thanks :)

Comment: You have syntax error. NSArray doesn't have "objectForKey" method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *allDataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];

NSArray *feed = [allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"results"];

for (NSDictionary *item in feed) {
    NSString *text = [item objectForKey:@"text"];
    [array addObject:text]; <- I assume this is NSMutableArray
}

[[self myTableView]reloadData];
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are calling:

```
    NSString *text = [feed objectForKey:@"text"];
```

Look closely:

```
[feed objectForKey:@"text"];
```

The object `feed` is an `NSArray`:

```
    NSArray *feed = [allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"results"];
```

And obviously `NSArray`'s do not have the method `objectForKey:`, thats a dictionary.

So either a typo or confusion or misunderstanding of Objective-C on your end.